# my javascript isn't computing accurately

Tags: javascript

I have 3 textboxes, one takes in a value, the other calculates 20% of that value and subtracts it from the the initial value. its doesn't work accurately.

Here is my code.

```js
function sum() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
  var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt4').value;
  var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * 0.2;
  var balance = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) -
    parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);


  if (!isNaN(result)) {

    document.getElementById('txt3').value = balance;
    document.getElementById('txt4').value = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" />
<input type="text" id="txt4" />
```

Comment: What does not work? Need to say what the issue is.

Comment: Probably another floating point problem...

Comment: Is the problem is the `NaN` which appears in the second input when you type in the first?

Comment: You try to pull the value from text box 4 before anything is entered. "_one takes in a value, the other calculates 20% of that value and subtracts it from the the initial value_" If this is the case you should never be grabbing any of the values from the other boxes, the first one is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to get the computed result before you compute it

```
document.getElementById('txt4').value
```

always is one step back, which won't work as you want it to.

What you really want to do is to calculate the balance using the `result`:

```
var balance = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) - result;
```

Note that I've replaced `parseInt` with `parseFloat`. That way the code will support floating numbers as an input too.

```js
function sum() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
  var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) * 0.2;
  var balance = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) - result;


  if (!isNaN(result)) {

    document.getElementById('txt3').value = balance;
    document.getElementById('txt4').value = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" />
<input type="text" id="txt4" />
```